# How to properly round numpy float arrays

Tags: python, scipy, args, minimization

I have some sort of rounding issue when rounding floats.

```
x = np.array([[1.234793487329877,2.37432987432],[1.348732847,8437.328737874]])
np.round(x,2)

array([[  1.23000000e+00,   2.37000000e+00],
       [  1.35000000e+00,   8.43733000e+03]])
```

Is there a way to display these numbers without the zero extensions?

Comment: How are you going to display them - with a print statement?

Comment: @wwii For example, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rounding floating point numbers is almost never needed (unless you want to bucket them, then your code will work just fine), if you only want to print them with less precision, use this:

```
print(np.array_str(x, precision=2))
```

Comment: I need to print them for debugging.